# ZSH alias printf

Tags: unix, terminal, alias, zsh

I'm trying to use zsh alias to make my `ls` command print out my files in a prettier format using `printf`. In my `.zshrc` file I have this line:

```
alias lsp="printf '|%15s |%15s |%15s |\n' $(ls)"
```

For some reason when I enter 'lsp' into the command line I get:`zsh: command not found: lsp`

I'm trying to figure out why my alias isn't working, for example right above I have one that works using: `alias la="ls -la"`, when I type `la` it spits out the proper command.

I'm guessing something with my quotation marks is off, does anybody have an idea?

Comment: You can - and probably should - use globbing instead of using the output of `ls`: `alias lsp="printf '|%15s |%15s |%15s |\n' *"`. Besides not needing to run an external command, it has the advantage of actually working with filenames that contain whitespaces. The output of `ls` is meant for human consumption and it is hard to parse it correctly for non-trivial cases. For machine-use either use `find` or make use of the many features `zsh` has to offer in regards to globbing.

Answer (score 0):

It does works with `zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. Don't forgot to source `.zshrc` after adding alias.

```
. .zshrc
```